# Add multiple rows to SharePoint List from Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have a data form where I want one button to be able to add multiple rows of data to a SharPoint List. The list looks like this:

```
Batch | Part | Date | Time | Test | Result
```

The issue is that there 5 tests per Batch and Part combination. I want one input field for the Batch, Part, Date, and Time. Then I want 5 fields for the Test Number and 5 fields for the results. Once clicking the Submit button, the data would like like this:

```
Batch | Part | Date   | Time | Test | Result
1       1      1/1/19   30      1      10
1       1      1/1/19   30      2      11
1       1      1/1/19   30      3      10
1       1      1/1/19   30      4      15
1       1      1/1/19   30      5      19
```

I know I can have the user put in the Test and Result, Submit, and then only reset those fields. I would like to be able to Submit all data at once instead of needing to press Submit 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can save those 5 records is a collection, and then patch all the collection to your sharepoint list.
To patch all rows of a collection:

```
ForAll(CollectionName, Patch(SharePoint_ListName, Defaults(SharePoint_ListName), { ColumnName1: value1, ColumnName2: value2, etc})
```

Where **ColumnName1** is the name of the column in your sharepoint list, and **value1** is the name of the column in your collection.